# How to define the number of version code for android project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In `build.gradle` file, there is an attribute called `versionCode`. Whenever I make an update to the project, should I increase the value of `versionCode`?

Comment: You should increase versionCode by one and versionName as like 1.1.1

Comment: you may read this http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html#appversioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**android:versionCode —**

> An integer value that represents the version of the application code,
>   relative to other versions.
>
> Typically, you would release the first version of your application
>   with versionCode set to 1, then monotonically increase the value with
>   each release, regardless whether the release constitutes a major or
>   minor release. This means that the `android:versionCode` value does
>   not necessarily have a strong resemblance to the application release
>   version that is visible to the user. Applications and publishing
>   services should not display this version value to users.

Screenshot of `versionCode` at Play Store Developer Console:

[image]

**android:versionName —**

> A string value that represents the release version of the application
>   code, as it should be shown to users.

Screenshot of `versionName` in Already Published app at Play Store:

[image: Screenshot of Play Store Developer Console:]

**Summary:** Version code is for keeping track of your application update, which is basically used when you upload a new apk in the Play Store. On the other hand `versionName` is a String that is visible to user so that they can see there's a new version available.

Source: [Versioning Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the versionCode for any new version you plan to release on Google Play (or whatever other distribution channels you use) as an update to the existing version. For internal testing, you don't have to increment the versionCode since you can force a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

If u plan on publishing your app to playstore then each update must have different verionCode and versionName is simply for developers to keep track of major changes and updates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the value of version code **only when you are publishing the app** otherwise there is no need to increase it. You can continue with the same version code